# Perl parse email and attachments from Outlook inbox

Tags: perl, email, parsing, mime

I'm using [`Mail::IMAPClient`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mail::IMAPClient) to connect to our Outlook mail server. I can get the mail just fine and print the text version of that mail to a file. But I'm having trouble using [`MIME::Parser`](https://metacpan.org/pod/MIME::Parser) to parse through the email.

I've tried giving the parser a file handle to the text file that I wrote the email to. I've tried giving the parser just the text of the email but it won't work how I'm expecting it to work. The entity parts always equals 0.

When I dump the entity skeleton I get

```
  Content-type: text/plain
  Effective-type: text/plain
  Body-file: NONE
  --
```

I can see all of the parts of the email in the file. The two PDFs that are attached are there, encoded in base64, so I know that the script is actually retrieving the email and the attachments. I've also tried `parse` and `parse_data`.

```
my $msgCount = 0;    
$msgCount = $imap->message_count();    
#or abortMission("", "Could not get message count: ". $imap->LastError );

if ( $msgCount > 0 ) {     

    #get all the messages from the inbox folder    
    my @msgseqnos = $imap->messages
            or abortMission("", "Could not retreive messages:". $imap->LastError);

    my ($x, $bh, $attachment, $attachmentName);

    foreach my $seqno ( @msgseqnos ) {

        my $input_file;
        my $parser = new MIME::Parser;
        my $emailText = $imap->body_string($seqno)   # should be the entire email as text. 
                or abortMission("", "Could not get message string: " . $imap->LastError);

        $parser->ignore_errors(1);
        $parser->output_to_core(1);

        open my $emailFileHandle, ">", "invoiceText.txt";
        print $emailFileHandle $emailText;
        #$imap->message_to_file($emailFileHandle, $seqno);

        my $entity = $parser->parse_data($emailText);
        $entity->dump_skeleton;

        if ( $entity->parts > 0 ) {

            for ( my $i = 0; $i < $entity->parts; $i++ ) {

                my $subentity = $entity->parts($i);

                # grab attachment name and contents
                foreach $x ( @attypes ) {

                    if ( $subentity->mime_type =~ m/$x/i ) {

                        $bh = $subentity->bodyhandle;
                        $attachment = $bh->as_string;
                        $attachmentName = $subentity->head->mime_attr('content-disposition.filename');

                        open FH, ">$attachmentName";
                        print FH $attachment;
                        close FH;

                        #push @attachment, $attachment;
                        #push @attname, $subentity->head->mime_attr('content-disposition.filename');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            stillAGo("eData VehicleInvoices problem", "Perl can't find an attachment in an email in the VehicleInvoices folder of eData email address");
        }

        close $emailFileHandle;

        # say $emailText;
        # next;

        #open OUT_FILE, ">invoiceText.txt";
        #print OUT_FILE $emailText;
        #print OUT_FILE $imap->bodypart_string($seqno,1);
        #close OUT_FILE;

        #print $emailText;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to retrieve the attachments from emails automatically and save them to disk to be processed by another job.

I'd like to include the `invoiceText.txt` file so people can see the actual output but it's 1200 lines long. I'm not sure where to upload a file to link in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `body_string` method doesn't return the entire email. As the documentation describes, and the name implies, it returns the *body* of the message, excluding the headers. That is why `dump_skeleton` shows no headers apart from the defaults

What you probably want, although I haven't tried it, is `message_string`, which *does* return the entire email

I see you've used `message_to_file` but commented it out. That would probably have worked if you got `MIME::Parse` to read from the file

Comment: I tried using message_to_file and then handing the parser the file handle but that didn't seem to work. I might have been using the parser incorrectly. Using message_string and parser->parse_data is working. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. The reason that didn't work is probably because you don't close `$emailFileHandle` to flush the data to disk (or you could `flush $emailFileHandle` but there's little point). Your current code has the same fault, but you're not using the file. But you shouldn't need to save the information to disk anyway -- you can write `$parser->parse_data($imap->message_string($seqno))`

Comment: Oh, and you could also `$imap->message_to_file('invoiceText.txt')` and then `$parser->parse_open('invoiceText.txt')` which has the same effect